# Why did the number of live rows fetched by index scans drop after table ANALYZE?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

We use PostgreSQL 12 and have a simple table, `event_participant`, storing 100 GBs of data.
`event_participant` has all the necessary indexes, so all rows are fetched using them, i.e., no rows are fetched using sequential scans.

Usually, it fetches 65 rows/second, but one day at 10 AM, we ran a planned campaign where the number of fetched rows using index scans jumped to 5.4 M rows/second. However, the number of index scans stayed the same at 200 per second. Table content started changing slowly but not enough to trigger autoanalyze because `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` is 0.01 or 1% of the table size.

Worth mentioning is that we configured `plan_cache_mode` TO `force_custom_plan` on this database because our app uses Prepared Statements, and we want to avoid generic plans because of live campaigns.

After 3 hours of huge CPU load and index scans, we manually performed an `ANALYZE` of the `event_participant`, and the number of live rows fetched by index scans immediately dropped from **5.4 M rows/sec to 450 rows/sec**.

I'm trying to figure out how the `ANALYZE` command impacted the number of live rows fetched by index scans, while the number of index scans stayed the same.

Update - including more details about the table structure and indexes.

```sql
> \d+ event_participant
                            Table "public.event_participant"
  Column  |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 event_id | text             |           | not null |         | extended |              | 
 user_id  | bigint           |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 progress | text             |           | not null |         | extended |              | 
 level    | integer          |           | not null | 0       | plain    |              | 
 quality  | double precision |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "event_participant_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id, event_id)
    "event_participant_event_id_idx" btree (event_id)
Access method: heap
```

So, at 10 AM, the campaign with a new event started (new event_id), and the `event_participant` table started growing. At every user login, the backend app, knowing which events are active, selects all entries by user_id and event_id: `SELECT * from event_participant WHERE user_id=? AND event_id=?;` to pick up the user's progress.

Comment: Without seeing the actual plans, none of this makes sense.  It is like you are giving us a slide presentation, only none of us can see the slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, since the event started, the `event_participant` table started growing but not enough to trigger `autovacuum_analyze,` which would update the query plan.

Before the event started at 10 AM, the event with `event_id=tour2023` didn't exist in the table, so during the latest autovacuum_analyze, which happened hours before, the query plan was not aware of `tour2023`, so it suggested using index  `event_participant_event_id_idx.` I tested the hypothesis by running an EXPLAIN SELECT with non-existing event_id; it uses the index created on it and then filters rows by user_id:

```
explain select * from event_participant where user_id = 1 and event_id = 'bla';
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using event_participant_event_id_idx on event_participant  (cost=0.56..1.61 rows=1 width=1409)
   Index Cond: (event_id = 'bla'::text)
   Filter: (user_id = 1)
```

which means that after event `tour2023` started while running query `SELECT * from event_participant WHERE user_id=? AND event_id=?;` PostgreSQL used `event_participant_event_id_idx` to fetch all rows with `event_id=tour2023` and then filter desired row by `user_id` instead of using the composite index `"event_participant_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id, event_id)`. This led to the increased number of lines fetched by index scans, as well as huge CPU usage.

After running `ANALYZE` manually, the query plan was updated, and the database decided to use a composite index. Hence, index scans' number of fetched rows dropped to 450 rows/sec.

EXPLAIN output when using existing event_id:

```
explain select * from event_participant where user_id = 1 and event_id = 'tour2023';
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using event_participant_pkey on event_participant  (cost=0.56..2.58 rows=1 width=1409)
   Index Cond: ((user_id = 1) AND (event_id = 'tour2023'::text))
```

So, the answer is that the query plan was stale, and PostgreSQL decided to use a sub-optimal index.

I'm still missing part of why PostgreSQL used the (event_id) index only, as I expected the query planner to favor the composite index when both user_id and event_id are specified in the query.